# Regex numbers after letters

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
/\d+(?!\d| |[a-zA-Z])/gm
```

and this string:

```
,98dépo 58 cou54lis 
GU966,1800,1900,2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000
1600.00,1841.00,1882.80,1898.50,1914.30,1930.00,1945.80,1993.40,2009.20,2028.50,2044.30,2061.50,2095.30,2111.1
```

I don't want to match the any numbers in ',98dépo 58 cou54lis GU966' but all others yes.

How can I do this?
thanks

Comment: This is just comma separated, you can explode and check `is_numeric` no need for regex

Comment: @apokryfos That should do it.. Looking at the pattern structure itself would help you start with some situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern: `~[\v,]\K\b[.\d]+\b~`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mAy8H8/3)

All of your valid numbers have a comma or vertical white-space before them.

```
$string=',98dépo 58 cou54lis 
GU966,1800,1900,2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000
1600.00,1841.00,1882.80,1898.50,1914.30,1930.00,1945.80,1993.40,2009.20,2028.50,2044.30,2061.50,2095.30,2111.1';

var_export(preg_match_all('~[\v,]\K\b[.\d]+\b~',$string,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1800',
  1 => '1900',
  2 => '2000',
  3 => '2100',
  4 => '2200',
  5 => '2300',
  6 => '2400',
  7 => '2500',
  8 => '2600',
  9 => '2700',
  10 => '2800',
  11 => '2900',
  12 => '3000',
  13 => '1600.00',
  14 => '1841.00',
  15 => '1882.80',
  16 => '1898.50',
  17 => '1914.30',
  18 => '1930.00',
  19 => '1945.80',
  20 => '1993.40',
  21 => '2009.20',
  22 => '2028.50',
  23 => '2044.30',
  24 => '2061.50',
  25 => '2095.30',
  26 => '2111.1',
)
```

This adjustment of apokryfos' method returns the same expected result as my regex method.

```
var_export(array_filter(explode(',',str_replace(PHP_EOL,',',$string)),'is_numeric'));
```

It merely prepares the string for explosion by converting newline characters to commas.

Comment: @J.Litvak fixed

Answer (score 3):

Use a sane solution:

```
$numbers = array_filter(explode(",", str_replace(["\r\n","\n","\r"],",", $string)), 'is_numeric');
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/958360336537ba5c4c99cba7e18419738045f407

Comment: I think this is unsuitable because of `3000` then newline then `1600.00`.

Comment: @mickmackusa That's a lot easier to resolve than trying to get a regex to differentiate between strings IP addresses and floating point numbers as well as scientific notation numbers (and signed numbers, must not forget about those). Fact is is_numeric is a central point of reference as to which strings are numeric while writing the millionth (probably wrong) regex to do that is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regexp:

```
/\n?([,\n](\d{1,}\.?\d{0,}))/
```

Usage:

```
$pattern = '/\n?([,\n](\d{1,}\.?\d{0,}))/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $match);

$values = $match[2];
```

Comment: Ok thanks but it always matcg commas and the first numbers ',98' too